# Cannot download FieldDefinition data for Contact object

Tags: soql, tooling-api, fielddefinition

I cannot download the FieldDefinition data using the Tooling API for all Contact fields.

I have used this query to get the Id for the Contact object:

```
SELECT Id FROM EntityDefinition where DeveloperName='Contact'
```

Which gives me an Id of 000000000000000AAA

I then use that Id in the following query:

```
SELECT DataType,Description,DeveloperName,DurableId,EntityDefinitionId, FROM FieldDefinition where EntityDefinitionId='000000000000000AAA'
```

But I get zero results returned.

I've also tried getting the Field Id via:

```
SELECT Id FROM CustomField WHERE TableEnumOrId = 'Contact'
```

This gives me 378 results, and then using that result for the IN part of the SOQL query

```
SELECT Id,Description,DataType FROM FieldDefinition where durableid IN
```

But again I get zero results.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's confusing based on the naming, but if you look closer at [FieldDefinition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_fielddefinition.htm#:%7E:text=QualifiedApi%E2%80%8BName%3D%27Lead%27-,EntityDefinitionId,-Type), you'll see that `EntityDefinitionId` is:

> The **durable ID** for the object defined in the EntityDefinition field.

In [EntityDefinition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_entitydefinition.htm), if you query `DurableId` instead of `Id` - you'll get the developer name of the object (ex. `Contact`)

```sql
SELECT DurableId
FROM EntityDefinition 
WHERE DeveloperName = 'Contact'

/* returns Contact for durableId */
```

As such, you'll want to pass the right value into your filter to get the results from `FieldDefinition`

```sql
SELECT DataType,DeveloperName,Description,DurableId,EntityDefinitionId 
FROM FieldDefinition 
WHERE EntityDefinitionId = 'Contact'
```

Comment: Thank you, will try this out

Comment: Thank you again, all works :)

Comment: Great - FYI, for [this site](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), even if you don't have enough rep to vote, you can accept an answer to your question if it's the best solution to your problem.

Comment: Tagging @Rich to accept the answer